# 3rd Conditional Question question

Tags: conditional-constructions, inversion

I understand the following sentence is correct:

> Had I stayed in Canada, I would have lived a good life.

But how should I form a question based on this sentence? Would the following be considered correct?

> Had I stayed in Canada, would I have lived a good life?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, or "Would I have lived a good life had I stayed in Canada?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is exactly correct.

The standard *inversion* for the interrogative, as you correctly surmised, changes "I would have lived..." to "would I have lived...".

Answer (score 0):

The question should not be on if-clause. Take a look at the following examples:

- Will you look after their dog again `if they go on holiday this year`?
- Would you mind `if I used your mobile`?
- Would you have been that strict `if you'd known the truth`?
- What would you do `if you were accused of murder`?

Comment: What is your point, exactly? Do you mean it should not begin with an if clause? The OP did not use any if clauses. And any of your examples could be reversed so as to start with the if clause, and would still be grammatically correct and semantically equivalent. Your answer is essentially a rhetorical question, stated as if it proves something.